# Unable to fetch a static json file

Tags: json, api, nginx

I have hosted a site for a static API coming from a JSON file. The fake API link is `api.example.com/db.json`.

While I am checking the URL with postman I am getting 200 status code. But while I am fetching it from Javascript it's showing this error `Access to fetch at 'http://api.example.com/db.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I am running the web server using nginx and it's a simple site package which have only one HTML page and that db.json file. Where I should add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com`?

**Also, I Tried json-server**

I even tried `json-server`. It's running locally but while I am hosting it in nginx server and tried to run `pm2 start --name=static_api npm run json:server`

pm2 showing this error

`[PM2] Starting /usr/local/bin/npm in fork_mode (1 instance)`

`[PM2] Done.`

`[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: /var/www/html/static_api/run`

Is there any way I can run the fake API aka `json-server` with Nginx?

Thanks.

Comment: Add `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com";` to your nginx server block (and other CORS headers the same way, if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com"; to your nginx server block (and other CORS headers the same way, if needed).

Answer by Ivan Shatsky